# How to segregate authentication mechanism of multiple controllers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a web application having endpoints of a Controller integrated to UI and and another set of endpoints exposed via REST Controller. UI Controller is authenticated via SSO while Rest Controller endpoints via basic authentication. Since UI Controller endpoints falls under request mapping (/) while rest controllers endpoints falls under "/non-ui/" , how can i prevent any person having sso access to ui from accessing "/non-ui" endpoints ?

Basically I would like to disable spring security on "/non-ui/" endpoints.

I have used below web security configuration to exclude. However, this means that any person having sso access to ui ("/") can access "/non-ui/**".

```
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/non-ui/**");
    }
```

If I use below suggestion, although it will deny anyone having access to ui from accessing "/non-ui/**" endpoints. However, it will also interfere if anyone try to access "/non-ui/**" endpoints via third party service because anyhow request will land on application only where denyAll is mentioned.

```
.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/non-ui/**")
                    .denyAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure 2 `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which UI and REST controller has their own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Each `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` represents a `SecurityFilterChain`.

When there are multiple `SecurityFilterChain`, it will check the `SecurityFilterChain` one by one according to the priority order .The first matched one will be used to process the request. So the ordering is important , you should configure the `SecurityFilterChain` with more specific URL patterns has higher priority than the one with more general URL pattern . Otherwise , the one with more general URL pattern will always matched first and ignore the one with the more specific URL pattern. It just like when we catch the exception in Java, we should catch a more specific exception first.

So in your case, the rest controllers (i.e /non-ui) has more specific URL pattern than the UI controller (i.e /) , it should have a higher priority :

```java
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RestApiSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/non-ui/**");
            //continue configure http ......
        }

}
```

The UI controller should have lower priority .Also need to deny it to access /non-ui :

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class UiSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**"); // Or you can ignore it as it will match everything by default
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/non-ui/**").denyAll();

            //continue configure http ......
        }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. However, I have 1 doubt, the non-ui endpoints are protected by some other service provider. So if anyone try to call directly those endpoints via postman or some other application, they set basic authentication.So with this case if I do not create RestApiSecurity and only with UiSecurity having lowest order, will still my scenario work or achievable?

Comment: no. My solution require to create two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. One for rest-api and one for ui . If you do not create `RestApiSecurity` , their endpoint will not be protected.

Comment: Suppose if rest endpoints (non-ui) are already protected by some third party service then we need not to protect them and to prevent those non-ui endpoints from being accessed by sso authorized people, we could use antMatchers("/non-ui/**").denyAll() in UiSecurity  as suggested by you.

Comment: what do you mean the rest endpoint is already protected by 3rd party service？ do you mean that its security is not controlled by you and you want to disable spring security to have any effect on its url？ if yes please update the question to make it more clear

Comment: You understood correctly. I want to disable spring security to have any effect on non-ui endpoint controller.Thanks for providing the right words to my use-case. Updated question as well

Comment: OK. Then doesn't it will already work if you simply just override the same `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` 's `WebSecurity` and `HttpSecurity` to the configuration that are already updated to in your questions at the same time ?

Comment: Finally I was able to test. However, denyAll did not restrict access. It's because I have ignore it from websecurity so httpSecurity denyAll cannot control.

Comment: I have posted another question related to this. Please provide some suggestion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67019986/how-to-know-if-request-is-made-via-oauth2-authorization