# How to know if request is made via oauth2 authorization?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, servlet-filters

I have certain endpoints "/ui/**" and "/non-ui/**". On "/ui/**" endpoints, Oauth2 code grant type is enabled. However, same ui user , after successful oauth2 login can access "/non-ui/**" endpoints also. Neither I want that ui user should be able to access "/non-ui/**" endpoints nor oauth2 login is enabled for "/non-ui/**" endpoints.

To exclude "/non-ui/**" endpoints from oauth2 login, I can use below code:

```
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/non-ui/**");
    }
```

How can I restrict ui users from accessing "/non-ui/**" endpoints. As above code just makes it public and ui users can access "/non-ui/**" endpoints ?

Is there a way by which I can get to know if request is made via oauth2 authentication ? I think by that way I can use some filter and control access.

**Some more context around the use-case.** As just now I added a security filter and removed "/non-ui/**" endpoints from webSecurity.ignoring() and got additional header information.

Since on non-ui endpoints basic authentication is already enabled and that's why I can get additional information from that i.e. if request was triggered via basic authentication mechanism or not. While same header fields are reflected as unauthenticated when non-ui endpoints are hit by UI users.

Based on this information , I will deny requests having unauthenticated header information. However, I am still unable to understand if authenticated non-ui request is made then how can i bypass oauth2 authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ROLES to users like ROLE_UI and ROLE_NONUI and check roles to access to endpoints by roles like

```
.antMatchers("/ui/*").hasRole("ROLE_UI")
```

or

```
.antMatchers("/non-ui").hasRole("ROLE_NONUI")
```

Comment: I have provide some more context. As already basic authentication enabled on non-ui endpoint, and from header i can decipher. So I cannot use Roles.